# Mocking and testing a function which returns text from an url

Tags: python, testing, beautifulsoup, mocking, pytest

I have a function which takes an url and returns the text from this url.

```
def extract_raw_text_from_url(url, set_parser='lxml'):

    try:
        req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})  # Set user agent as Mozilla. Otherwise: Error 403
        source = urlopen(req).read()  # Return source code

        parser = set_parser
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, parser)  # create beautiful soup object

        text = soup.get_text()  # get text of websites

    except (ValueError): # ToDo: Why urllib.error.URLError is unknown? I want to include it in exception! Works in Colab!
        text = []

    return text
```

How do I properly test this function? Since I think it's bad practise to make a request each time I run the test, I think it would be a nice idea to mock the result.

Any idea how to do this? I am using pytest but I'm still a beginner.

Comment: Can you reach to the url directly from the server?

Comment: Well, yes, if I insert an url, I can reach it and makes a real request. But I thought it would be best practice to write test, that do not be connected to the internet in order to work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it depends on what you want to test, if you want to test the request you should perform a request each time (in fact the webpage could change from one day to another and it takes into account that).

If you want to test the parsing procedure for a given html input, I think that you can download and put the html page in you *assets* (or whatever) folder inside the test and than you could try using

```
url = "assets/mywebpage1.html"
with open(url, 'r') as f:
   source = f.read()
   #...
```

EDIT:
I think that two approaches could be adopted:

1. Divide the 2 operations in two different functions and test just *parse_content_from_html(source)* where source is obtained as the example above inside the test routine

```py
def extract_raw_text_from_url(url, set_parser='lxml'):
    try:
        req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        source = urlopen(req).read()  # Return source code
        text = parse_content_from_html(source)
    except (ValueError): 
        text = []

    return text

def parse_content_from_html(source):
    parser = set_parser
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, parser)  # create beautiful soup object
    text = soup.get_text()  # get text of websites
    return text
```

2. Use a flag to distinguish a local html loading from a remote one. You can use `extract_raw_text_from_url("assets/mywebpage1.html", ..., local=True)`

```py
def extract_raw_text_from_url(url, set_parser='lxml', local=False):

    try:
        if local:
            with open(url, 'r') as f:
                source = f.read()
        else:
            req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})  # Set user agent as Mozilla. Otherwise: Error 403
            source = urlopen(req).read()  # Return source code

        parser = set_parser
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, parser)  # create beautiful soup object

        text = soup.get_text()  # get text of websites

    except (ValueError): 
        text = []

    return text
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My goal is to test the parsing procedure. Saving the website in a folder and loading the html-page is a good idea. However, I really don't know, how to write the complete test for the function ``extract_raw_text_from_url``. My issue is, that at some point within my test-function, I have to call the function ``extract_raw_text_from_url``  to compare its result with the expected result. Maybe you can show me, at what position in my test I have to use your code example?!

Comment: Added examples for your specific scenario, I hope one of them will be useful to you!